# Cache rendered pages from browser

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, caching, wkhtmltopdf

I have an interesting task.

I need to make page caching to database (full rendered page with executed javascript). I'm using symfony2 and i have an idea how I could do it: Probably I'll have to use `wkhtmltopdf` somehow to render the page and get the html markup after javascript is executed. The problem is that this is just and idea and I don't know how exactly you execute this idea of mine.
If you have a better idea than mine I'll be very happy.
Any help will be appreciate.

To be more clear:
Lets asume this is my page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        stuff...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        for(var i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
            $('#content').append('<p>'+i+'</p>');
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

and i want to get this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        stuff...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p>0</p>
            <p>1</p>
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need this to happen without the client browser to take part(this to be generated only on the server side)

Comment: Javascript is executed on the client, not the server. Given that it is often used to change the displayed HTML on-the-fly in response to user input, at what point will you cache the rendered HTML? This doesn't seem very practical.

Comment: In this case it is needed, i`m just looking for a solution. I need the markup of the page after all the javascript on page load is executed

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this with wkhtmltopdf, have you tried it? On the command line execute your example page with this:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe example.html example.pdf
```

That should pretty much work on the server without client interaction at all - the rest of the app is wiring and options (and lots and lots of coding indeed). Sometimes you need to add `--javascript-delay 5000` or such for longer running javascript. What else do you need really; it's hard to say. I would start by building a small mockup site and building ontop of that, trying out the most difficult and advanced cases that might be deal breakers.